# mysql connection fails after 3000+ attempts

Tags: mysql, database-connection, prolog, swi-prolog

I was just testing a small script in Prolog to sanity check the MySQL connection. The connection fails randomly, after making around 3000+ connections. Is there any limitation in MySQL Server for number of connections

```
:-dynamic db_connection/1.

sanity_check_open_db:-
            odbc_connect('myDSN', _,
            [ user(bob),
              password(pop),
              alias(myDSN),
              open(once)
            ]),

            (   db_connection(_),
                retractall(db_connection(_))
            ;   assert(db_connection(myDSN))).

sanity_chec_close:-
            (   db_connection(C),
                odbc_disconnect(C),
                retractall(db_connection(C))
            ;   write('Error: No connection opened to close')).

sanity_check_open_close(10000).

sanity_check_open_close(N):-
    format(atom(C),'~wth Iteration~n',[N]),
    write(C),
            sanity_check_open_db,
            sanity_chec_close,
            N1 is N + 1,!,
            sanity_check_open_close(N1).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP connections take kernel memory, even after they are closed.  If you say:

```
netstat -na |grep WAIT
```

I think you'll find that most of those 3000 connections are still in the TIME_WAIT state, which typically lasts 120 seconds.  It might be optimized to a lower value in your case, but still quite long, like 30 seconds.  If your program can make enough connections in that time, you can run the kernel out of memory reserved for keeping track of TCP connections.

Comment: But when I try the same script using MSSQL server, with 10000 connection attempt , it is going fine. This is a big surprise.

Comment: Do the netstat check.  You may find that the connections are left in some other state, either a different WAIT state or something like FIN_RCVD, which indicates that your underlying DB driver isn't closing the connection properly.

Comment: I guess since you accepted my answer, you came to some resolution.  Care to share?

Comment: MySQL behaves strange. I switched to MSSQL and it is ok now. I did not check if there is a problem with the driver, since I downloaded from MySQL website.